# Google fonts stopped working in my DNN website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, dotnetnuke

Late last week I recently discovered my google fonts stopped working in my DNN website. I have not been able to find a fix yet.

I had my google fonts installed so I missed that they suddenly stopped showing up properly.

After doing some testing I found if I put all the l classes at the bottom of the css file Im was able to make it look okay but I was unable to fix a few things. Like the second level navigation in our careers section.

Here is the website http://chartwell.com/index

Obviously I would like to figure out how to fix this in a less hack-y way.

here is how I call them originally;

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="STYLES" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Styles.ascx" %>
<dnn:STYLES runat="server" ID="GoogFonts" Name="GoogFonts"   StyleSheet="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Merriweather+Sans:400,700,300" UseSkinPath="false" />

h1 { color:#0072bc !important; line-height:90%;  letter-spacing:.5px; margin-bottom:5px !important; margin-top:-5px !important; font-size:28px !important;   font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Here is how I was doing the reset now that made it wok;

```
h1, .TitleH2 {  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400;  }
```

---

Hello I have been testing the font loader. It seems to fix the issue if I want to stay with the simple example at the top.

I notice down at the bottom there is this script for how to call fonts that have different weights;

```
<script>
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: {
            bfamilies: ['Montserrat:400,700']
        }
    };
</script>
```

I have tried many different edits with elements in different places and I'm stumped again.

Does anyone that knows this system have any insights for me?

Comment: Maybe try using Web Font Loader to serve up your fonts: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Comment: Thanks will give it a try hopefully I can get it to work with DNN it can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Hello Mark I edited my question a bit with one about fontloader. If you had a sec you think you can check? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I can be of much help since I don't have any experience with DotNetNuke. It sounds like your styles are being overridden somewhere, since you experience different results when you move your CSS to the end of the file. Try using your browser's web inspector to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. After I removed the bold after Montserrat in my font stack.

Thanks for your time.